# Bukkit ChatColor Translate Alternate Color Codes

Tags: java, bukkit

So I am making a plugin and in the plugin config file you can put things like &b or &a and I know that there's a bukkit chatColor function for this called `ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', AString)` but I don't understand what to put in AString. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It's explained right in the [bukkit javadocs](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html#translateAlternateColorCodes(char,%20java.lang.String)): it's the `textToTranslate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AString` in [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) says "a String".

You should place whatever text has the `&colorCodes` in it there. For example, if you have the String `&7Hello, &aWorld!`, and you wanted to get the color from it, you could use:

```
String myString = "&7Hello, &aWorld!";
String coloredString = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', myString);
```

Which would make `coloredString` equal to `ChatColor.GRAY + "Hello, " + ChatColor.GREEN + "World!"`.

Comment: Practically, "AString" is PascalCase (Upper camelCase: See "Variations" in your linked Wikipedia article) for "a String".